# MySQL Joining Table, Find Average Rating, and Rank

Tags: mysql, join, count, average

How do you calculate the average rating, then order by the highest average rating and number of votes?

Below is what I have so far...

`members` table

```
ID | name
---+------
 1 | Andrew
 2 | Anthony
 3 | John
 4 | Jane
```

`member_ratings` table

```
ID | id_gave_rating | id_rated | rating
---+----------------+----------+---------
 1 |        1       |     2    |    1
 2 |        2       |     3    |    4
 3 |        3       |     4    |    3
 4 |        4       |     2    |    5
```

current query

```
    $sql = "
    SELECT *, 
    m.id AS id, 
    c1.id AS id_rated, 
    c1.name AS name_rated
    FROM member_ratings AS m
    JOIN members AS c1 ON m.id_rated  = c1.id";
```

Targeted result

```
id_rated | avg_rating | votes
---------+------------+--------
    3    |      4     |    1
    2    |      3     |    2
    4    |      3     |    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `group by id_rated` in `member_ratings` and aggregate:

```
select id_rated, 
       avg(rating) avg_rating,
       count(*) votes
from member_ratings
group by id_rated
order by avg_rating desc, votes desc
```

If you want also the details of the member you can join to `members`:

```
select m.id, m.name, r.avg_rating, r.votes
from members m 
inner join (
  select id_rated, 
         avg(rating) avg_rating,
         count(*) votes
  from member_ratings
  group by id_rated
) r on r.id_rated = m.id
order by r.avg_rating desc, r.votes desc
```

Or:

```
select m.id, m.name, 
       avg(r.rating) avg_rating,
       count(*) votes
from members m inner join member_ratings r
on r.id_rated = m.id
group by m.id, m.name
order by avg_rating desc, votes desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=44ec0aa833ec89cf77bda7574955d3eb).